# Solution of DE regarding SHM, kinda

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, mathematics, differential-equations

## Firstly, let me explain the situation

So this year in my core module, modern physics, all of our practicals are simulations of general stuff programmed in SageMath/Jupyter Notebook. We are still in the beginning of our journey, so the work is still introductory. This week's practical is about SHM and the differential equations regarding it. We also had to make an equation which describes the height of beer froth.

The reason for the word "kinda" in the title is that I don't know if the specific DE I have in mind actually is SHM or not. The goal of this question is to establish whether or not my solution is correct.

### The SHM second order DE and Solution

So I know that the DE for SHM is $\;y''=-\omega^2y$ . In our practical we are dealing with damped SHM, so the DE is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = -k\,x(t)-c\,\frac{\mathrm{d}\,x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{equation}
My solution was $\;x(t) = \newcommand{\Bold}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{4} \, \sqrt{15} t\right) e^{\left(-\frac{1}{4} \, t\right)}$
The resulting graph was (just realized I forgot to add labels):[image: x over t]

## Now comes the actual question

So, they asked us to solve the equation $\;y''=\omega^2y$, as you can see, the only difference this has with the normal SHM equation is the lack of the minus sign in our new example.
The solution I (or rather SageMath) was (with $\omega=1$) $\;\newcommand{\Bold}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}y(t)=\frac{3}{2} \, e^{\left(-t\right)} + \frac{1}{2} \, e^{t}$ which yielded the graph (again no labels, sry)[image: IC set 1]

with different plots for different initial conditions (but all of them follow the same general curve, just for example down or up)

## The question is: is my solution for $\;y''=\omega^2y\;$ correct?

Comment: I would also like to point out that I THINK my solution is correct, because the function $\mathrm{e}^t$ is equal to itself after every  differentiation level. I would also like to point out that I am second year and the course IS modern physics, but the practicals themselves revolve around general physics, i.e. classical and modern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your function, y, solves the differential equation. The way to approach linear, homogeneous, ordinary differential equations is by setting up and finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial. For example, for the differential equation $x'' +c x' + kx=0$, the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2+c\lambda +k=0$. If we denote the roots of this polynomial as $\lambda _1$ and $\lambda_2$, the solution is a linear combination of $e^{\lambda _1 t}$ and $e^{\lambda _2 t}$, where the coefficients of these functions are determined by the inital conditions.

For $y''=\omega^2 y$, the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2 - \omega^2=0$ so the solutions are linear combinations of $e^{\omega t}$ and $e^{- \omega t}$, which is what you found. For SHM without damping, the roots are $i \omega$ and $-i \omega$, so the solution can be written as a combination of sines and cosines.